# Is there a way to limit the amount of RAM that Dart Editor uses up?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I found it was using 600 MB of RAM, even more than Visual Studio (which I shut down when it gets to 400 MB of RAM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dart editor is based on Eclipse which is in turn based on Java. You can tell java to limit the amount of memory an application can use on start-up in the init file.

In the `DartEditor.ini` file you can set the maximum memory size to use. Here 1400 Mo

```
-Xmx1400m
```

This is a command line option to java.
More info on java command line options can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#options

or the java `man` pages.